# Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to recreate this json:

```
{
"request": {
        " TestRequest": {
            "OrderID": {
                "orderNumber": "12345",
                "category": "ABC"
            },
            "SecondCategory": "DEF"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing this:

```
JObject jObject = new JObject(new JProperty("request",
                  new JObject(
                    new JProperty("TestRequest",
                    new JObject(
                        new JProperty("OrderID",
                            new JProperty("orderNumber", "12345"),
                            new JProperty("category", "ABC")),
                            new JProperty("SecondCategory", "DEF")))))
                );
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Can not add `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty` to `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`

What am I doing wrong? And how Can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you have closing bracket for OrderID JProperty constructor in wrong place. You are passing all other JProperties as constructor argument to first.

Comment: Why not make proper C# classes? This can be done automatically, for example https://app.quicktype.io?share=vvC2FvwvPYnKoAgzI4M4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a lot easier if you just make an object:

```
var req = new
{
    request = new
    {
        TestRequest = new
        {
            OrderID = new
            {
                orderNumber = "12345",
                category = "ABC"
            },
            SecondCategory = "DEF"
        }
    }
};

var reqSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req, Formatting.Indented);
```

Output:

```
{
  "request": {
    "TestRequest": {
      "OrderID": {
        "orderNumber": "12345",
        "category": "ABC"
      },
      "SecondCategory": "DEF"
    }
  }
}
```

The anonymous object doesn't have to have a concrete type associated with it, just create the format almost as the JSON you show and then serialize it normally.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried doing that, but when I check the "req" object after it runs, I see the orderNumber and category is flipped ,meaning, category is being passed first and then orderNumber, causing the request to fail. Any idea why that's occuring?

Comment: I don't know, [here is a DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZmoEfu) showing it working properly.

Comment: You are correct and after reading your response I abandoned the Newtonsoft JSON method and created an object instead, problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Ron Beyer's answer is simpler for a declarative initializations. **But** your programmatic approach addresses other needs... and you were pretty close to get it working.

The exception message you got is often thrown when trying to add a JProperty into a JProperty's value. Although we can't put a JProperty directly into another one, we can add a JObject in a JProperty, and this JObject can, in its turn, contain JProperty(ies). In this specific case **a JObject wrapper is missing** around  JProperties "*orderNumber*" and "*category*".

The corrected code should look like below:

```
JObject jObject = new JObject(new JProperty("request",
              new JObject(
                new JProperty("TestRequest",
                new JObject(
                  new JProperty("OrderID",
                    new JObject(      //********* add a JObject( here 
                        new JProperty("orderNumber", "12345"),
                        new JProperty("category", "ABC"))),  //******* ...and here insert the corresponding closing parenthesis
                    new JProperty("SecondCategory", "DEF")))))
            );
```